# asyncTask from 3rd tab called in first tab in View pager fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

i used view pager inside tab view i had 3 tabs in my activity. each tab having a fragment. i called asyncTask in OnCreateView of all tabs. everything is working fine. but the problem is comes when i come on first tab asynctask from all others 2nd tab or 3rd tab also gets called in first tab.here is my code snippet.

**TabActivity :**

```
  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

**FirstTab:**

```
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current, container, false);



 RequestNetworkcall();
return view;}
```

i am stuck on this problem from last 2 days lease help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Viewpager always initializes it's three pages, like it's visible.
So that means all your pages have already called their onResume() method.

You need to call your asynctask when that page is selected.

UPDATE:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 3) {
                //Call your asynctask here
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i know which page is selected.?

Comment: i tried it and call my asynctask method from tab activity. but it throws NPE  in onPost() when i save response in sqlite.